# import win32ui in python 3.6

Tags: python, pywin

I downloaded pywin32 from the website. I've got those imports:

```
from pywin32 import win32gui
from pywin32 import win32ui
from pywin32 import win32con
```

It doesn't work at all, but the first import works if i replace pywin32 with win32. Like this

```
from win32 import win32gui
from pywin32 import win32ui
from pywin32 import win32con
```

For the second one i've got this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywin32'
```

What should i do?

Comment: First, make sure you have installed the latest version of pywin32, now in GitHub: [https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases)

Answer (score 2):

`pywin32` doesn't expose a module named `pywin32`. Instead, it separates out into multiple modules that map to various parts of the Windows API.

So for you, the import statements should look like:

```
from win32 import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
```